# How to set a breakpoint on a Class NOT a Line in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

**I simply would like to start debugging once any function is invoked in a specific set of classes.**

Is it possible to achieve this in Eclipse ? 
or do I have to set a breakpoint on each function in each class I want to debug?

**UPDATE:**

I didn't ask how to set a breakpoint in eclipse. I would like to debug a class without knowing which function is going to be called.

**UPDATE 2:**

(I am going to make my problem more clear)

I was requested to fix a bug in an application (Which I didn't implement). I managed to narrow down the related classes to this bug. The problem each class has over 30 functions. And I don't know exactly which functions are invoked. So I was thinking if its possible to set a breakpoint *somehow* on the class itself in order to start debugging once a function within this class is invoked.

I would appreciate any help,

Tefa

Comment: Put a method level break point on every method of that class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think you can select a class for debugging but you could go to the `Outline` view in eclipse, select all the methods in the class, right click and select `Toggle Method Breakpoint`

[image]

Comment: Just small additional - unselect abstract methods before call context menu. For me menu was unavailable when abstract methods selected

Answer (score 6):

In recent eclipse versions, the feature you were searching for is now available.

In the Outline you may right-click on the class and choose "Toggle Class Load Breakpoint" from the context-menu.

Comment: Class load happens once. OP wanted a breakpoint when entering any function in the class.