# Put a breakpoint on every line in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Is there a way to put a breakpoint on every line in Eclipse?

The reason I ask is because I am analyzing a proxy program written in Java, which waits and listens for connections. I'm trying to follow how it works, but I can't figure out where the code starts from when a connection arrives.

How can I trigger a breakpoint no matter where the code starts from, in other words, breakpoint every line?

Comment: Would a class load breakpoint be a good thing here? See Run -> Add Class load breakpoint...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't think of a reason you'd want a breakpoint on every line. It would be equivalent to simply putting a breakpoint at the first line of `main()`, then stepping through your program with `step into` -- not something a sane person would normally want to do with a large program.

I would suggest:

1. Delete or disable any breakpoints you have already
2. Start your proxy in debug mode; allow it to initialise. It is now listening.
3. Hit the "pause" button in the debug controls. You might have to select the right thread to pause -- experiment.
4. Look at the stack display, this will show you where it's paused. It will probably be paused in a library class - follow the stack up to your own code.

If you like, you can now connect to your proxy with a client, and use the debug step controls to watch how the code handles it. One problem with this is that things time out while you're looking at steps, so it can be useful to set longer timeouts where possible.

Comment: As I explained, it's because I can't see where the triggers to certain action are. So for example, I run the program with main, and then it sleeps until something happens. I want to start following it from the moment it's triggered

Comment: Do you understand what I mean by "follow the stack up"? I can add more detail if necessary.

Comment: An example usage of doing what the question asks is you are in a unfamiliar code base and you want to check if any code in a particular class runs. For example, you might be trying to check where/if a Java FX application classes getting executed

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy To do that you wouldn't want to "put a breakpoint on every line".

Comment: The question is asking for something like Chrome's "break on next" for Javascript. I had an exception being thrown before arriving at my REST endpoint and had no way of knowing that ContainerRequestFilter, ExceptionMapper, and JaxRS were all touching my JSON before it arrived at my class.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can add a breakpoint for each row at a time.
However, you can debug row by row by clicking "Debug as" then using the following commands : [F6] "Step Over" and [F5] "Step Into".

Comment: That absolutely the way to go but the problem still would be where to start. At least that's what I read from the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

From StackOverFlow site reference

I don't think you can select a class for debugging but you could go to the `Outline view` in eclipse, select all the methods in the class, right click and select `Toggle Method Breakpoint`

[How to set a breakpoint on a Class NOT a Line in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148420/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-class-not-a-line-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a breakpoint in every line would be overkill so I'd put a breakpoint at a line that I know is passed and then walk up the call stack to get the entry point, i.e. use the "Debug" view where the threads and the current stack are listed.

Once you found that entry point you could set a breakpoint there and then step through the code using the normal debugger commands like "step into", "step over" etc.

Btw, AFAIK setting a breakpoint in every line with a few actions is not even possible in eclipse, because it wouldn't make much sense. There might be a way by creating a .bkpt file for every line in the code and import those, but I neither don't know how you would create such a file nor do I think that Eclipse would be able to handle such a potenially huge amount of breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow arrow that " hits " between two black dots , imagine that our program has the breakpoint on a line on which a call is made to a method and has stopped there. By pressing this button, the debugger will get inside the method and stop at the first line of the same , so we can debug inside the method . For example, where the breakpoint is shown in the following figure.

[image]

Pressing the button marked in red , the debugger will get inside the echaCuentas ( ) method and stop at the first line of that method.
The next button , a yellow arrow jumping over a black point , goes a step program execution , but without getting into the method that you find. For example , in the previous figure , if push this button , the execution would pass line System.out.println ( ) , without stopping within echaCuentas ( ) method .

Finally , the last button is an arrow from between two black dots , advances the program until we got out of the current method and go to the place where it has been called .

Comment: I'd guess the OP knows that, the problem seems to be where to start, i.e. where to put the first breakpoint.

Comment: In firts line of the file (i.e. in package)

Comment: AFAIK you can't set a breakpoint on a package declaration and not always is it the first line or method of a class that is used. You can't just set the breakpoint at an arbitrary line and hope the program hops right into it if you don't know how that program works (and the OP doesn't know that, he tries to learn by debugging, hence the question).

Comment: Please read the question more thoroughly, the OP knows how to debug, he just don't know where to start. And that is actually a good question sometimes using large (web) applications where there is just not simply one single main method as a root.

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoint in every line is not possible... Put the breakpoint where you want in your code or else do it manually.. Then degug your application; it will stop on the breakpoint line;